# Как разбить строку по токену?

Tags: c++, строки

Есть строка, которую нужно разбить по разделителю и сохранить результат в структуру. Какой наилучший (наиболее быстрый по скорости работы) алгоритм для этого можно использовать? Хотелось бы что-то наподобие сериализатора XML в C#.

Пример строки:

```
0,303567,3584,w,0.000000
```

Структура:

```
struct REQUEST{
    unsigned int asu;
    unsigned int lba;
    long size;
    char opcode;
    double timestamp;

    REQUEST()
    {
        asu = 0;
        lba = 0;
        size = 0;
        opcode = ' ';
        timestamp = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос не совсем корректен. С одной стороны вы хотите готовое решение (встроенный в библиотеку алгоритм), а с другой наиболее быстрое по скорости. Так не бывает. Наиболее быстрый - это который пишется вручную. Берёте строку и парсите её символ за символом. Это быстрее встроенных библиотечных функций в разы, при прямых руках.

Comment: @Zealint, то есть, по-старинке, перебирать всё с помощью while, записывать во временный буфер, а потом пихать в структуру? Я думал, есть способ красивее.

Comment: Да, но Вы сами сказали, что нужен быстрый алгоритм. Он будет быстрым. Любые библиотечные функции, конечно, будут красивее (и вам уже дали хороший ответ ниже), но они рассчитаны на универсальные случаи, поэтому там больше всяких проверок и т. д. Они медленнее. Мне кажется, Вы вряд ли хотите именно самое быстрое решение... Я просто выразил своё мнение по корректности формулировки вопроса.

Comment: @Zealint, возможно, я как-то не так выразился, но в данном случае между красотой и быстротой я выбираю **быстроту**, потому что таких строк будет много, и чем быстрее они распарсятся - тем лучше. Поэтому скорость в данном случае первостепенна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кажется, идиоматический вариант на C++ такой:

```
using namespace std;

istream& getrecord(istream& s, REQUEST& req)
{
    string part;
    bool result = 
        getline(s, part, ',') &&
            (istringstream(part) >> req.asu) &&
        getline(s, part, ',') &&
            (istringstream(part) >> req.lba) &&
        getline(s, part, ',') &&
            (istringstream(part) >> req.size) &&
        getline(s, part, ',') &&
            ((part.size() == 1) ? (req.opcode = part[0], true) : false) &&
        getline(s, part, ',') &&
            (istringstream(part) >> req.timestamp);
    if (!result && s)
        s.setstate(ios::failbit);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    string original("0,303567,3584,w,0.000000");

    REQUEST req;
    istringstream origs(original);
    if (getrecord(origs, req))
        cout << "asu = " << req.asu << ", lba = " << req.lba <<
                ", size = " << req.size << ", opcode = " << req.opcode <<
                ", timestamp = " << req.timestamp;
    else
        cout << "FAILED";
}
```

К сожалению, `stringstream` не умеет читать в `char`, поэтому получилось не так красиво.

Проверка: http://ideone.com/IPtprZ

Comment: это что за нагромождение &&, издеваетесь? :)

Comment: @ixSci: Ну, такой себе метод управлять control flow :)

Comment: @ixSci: скорректировал, чтобы отправляло поток в fail-состояние при ошибке.

Comment: @VladD, timestamp не считывается, у меня все значения нули там((( может это связано с форматом числа? Что точка после нуля, а должна быть запятая, чтобы число могло быть приобразовано к типу double?

Comment: @VladD, нашёл баг. Нужно поставить скобки для всего выражения в строке, где получается символ. Должно быть так: ( (part.size() == 1) ? (req.opcode = part[0], true) : false ) &&

Comment: @neo: Правда? Окей, исправлю в ответе :)

Comment: @neo: А с числом типа `double` — попробуйте написать в начале `main` следующее: `std::locale::global(std::locale(""));`

Comment: @neo: Это если исправление предыдущего бага (со скобками) не помогло.

Comment: @VladD, не, всё ок))) Скобочки помогли)

Comment: @neo: Отлично, значит, добили :)

Answer (score 3):

Например, `strtok` с преобразованием строк в нужный тип (и проверкой ошибок).

Вариант с внесением в `stringstream` с последующим разбором, пожалуй, по эффективности будет похуже.

Comment: Можете обосновать:
**"Вариант с внесением в stringstream с последующим разбором, пожалуй, по эффективности будет похуже"**?

Comment: Да что тут обосновывать? Одно только перенесение в памяти туда-сюда, накладные расходы всяческие, обработки ошибок в потоках... Да просто напишите тестовую программу и сравните - в результатах уверен :)